# How to consume SOAP Web Service secured with OAuth in Mule 4

Tags: soap, mulesoft, anypoint-studio, mule4, mule-connector

I want to consume a OAuth secured SOAP API in Mule 4. I want to know how can I pass the bearer token in a header.

I tried almost all the things by using transport header and writing as edit inline with key as Authorization and value as Bearer TOKEN_VALUE.

However nothing is working. Let me know how to consume it.

Comment: Please share the configurations and operations you have, and the resulting error or messages. Read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: This question has been answered at https://stackoverflow.com/a/72172499/721855.