# Add HTTP headers to SOAP web service

Tags: mule-studio, mulesoft, mule-component

I am using Web service consumer in Mule4 and I need to pass http header for passing Authentication details to the SOAP service, in Web service consumer there is headers section but it is for SOAP headers, but I could not find how to add HTTP headers.

Did anyone face similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

It is literally in the documentation: https://docs.mulesoft.com/web-service-consumer-connector/1.6/web-service-consumer-config-topics#configure-custom-http-transport

By default the Web Service Consumer uses its own HTTP Request configuration. You can explicitly configure it to use your own HTTP Request configuration, in which you can define HTTP [built-in authorization options](https://docs.mulesoft.com/http-connector/1.7/http-authentication), like HTTP Basic Authentication, [custom HTTP headers](https://docs.mulesoft.com/http-connector/1.7/http-request-ref#configure-headers), or any other HTTP Request configurations (like HTTPS options).

Example:

```xml
<http:request-config name="basic-auth">
    <http:request-connection host="www.exampleplace.com" port="8182" protocol="HTTP">
        <http:authentication>
            <http:basic-authentication username="admin" password="textpassword"/>
        </http:authentication>
    </http:request-connection>
</http:request-config>

<wsc:config name="with-custom-transport">
    <wsc:connection wsdlLocation="http://www.host.com?WSDL" service="Service" port="Port">
        <wsc:custom-transport-configuration>
            <wsc:http-transport-configuration requesterConfig="basic-auth"/>
        </wsc:custom-transport-configuration>
    </wsc:connection>
</wsc:config>
```

Comment: I am trying to configure my own HTTP Request configuration and when i try to configure the endpoint, I see HTTP host, port and base path and I could not find Path field to mention Path

Comment: You don't need to configure a path for using with the Web Service Consumer. The HTTP configuration let's you set a optional base path, but it is maybe useful in some cases with REST APIs.

Comment: but in my own HTTP request configuration, I need to define host, port, base path and path right, you mean only host and port are sufficient and no need of base path and path ?

Comment: That's right. The Web Service Consumer will override the path dynamically at execution time. I added the example from the documentation. Even if you are doing plain HTTP requests the base path is optional.

Comment: further when I try to add the configuration and deploy and trigger it, while Web service consumer is invoked I am getting the below error: " Error reading XMLStreamReader: Undeclared namespace prefix "soapenv"
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,14]" , Any reason why I am getting this error?

Comment: Seems that you are getting a response from the server. Unless it is receiving an error it means that it authenticated and then it got some other error. You can create a separate question for that other issue.